# ffmpeg: colortemperature filter and sunrise/sunset lights compensation

Tags: ffmpeg

I wish to compensate video for morning and evening lights with ffmpeg filter. I found in https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#colortemperature and was hoping to make use this filter.
Below is the command I added but doesn't seems to compensate for lights. Are there any filters to use for such case?

-vf colortemperature=temperature=5000

Comment: I often wonder why people struggle with command-line video solutions when one of the world's finest video editing suites is available ***free*** for personal use. [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) - Mac, Win & Nix.

Comment: What does mean precisely *"doesn't seem to work"*? It stops with an error? It runs but doesn't produce the expected result? It changes nothing on the video? Can you show the full command?

Comment: @PierU sorry for misunderstanding. It was due to ffmpeg versions in linux distro that I didn't realize. Earlier when I tested, it show there was no such filter so I thought it didn't work.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thanks for the tool you suggested. I am not in the business of video editing. I just need to analyze surveillance video and identify motions; however, I came across problems related to sunrise & sunset lights. My tools require command line as it involves running on-line.

Comment: Please update your question with all relevant information

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [colortemperature](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colortemperature) filter "simulate variations in ambient color temperature".

It looks like the purpose is simulating photos/video without White Balance, that were taken in various illumination conditions.

The filter assumes that the input is color balanced to 6500K.

- When the filter is used with `temperature=3000` for example, the result is more reddish (simulating a photo taken in 3000K illumination before White Balance).
- When the filter is used with `temperature=8000` for example, the result is more blueish (simulating a photo taken in 8000K illumination before White Balance).

In general I assume the filter is quite useless for compensating for illumination conditions.
I would not trust the implementation to work for physically accurate simulation eather...

Color balancing (illuminant color compensation) supposed to be applied before most image processing stages - the input supposed to be raw video.
For getting accurate colors, we also require color correction matricis for the specific camera model.

---

Example for `colortemperature` filter output.

Original image:
[image]

Applying `temperature=6500` (output is the same as the original image).
`ffmpeg -y -i input.png -vf colortemperature=temperature=6500 -update 1 -frames:v 1 out6500.png`
[image]

Applying `temperature=3000` (simulating redish illuminant).
`ffmpeg -y -i input.png -vf colortemperature=temperature=3000 -update 1 -frames:v 1 out3000.png`
[image]

Applying `temperature=8000` (simulating blueish illuminant).
`ffmpeg -y -i input.png -vf colortemperature=temperature=8000 -update 1 -frames:v 1 out8000.png`
[image]

Comment: Currently I run scene score detection on various camera feeds and it seems that every morning around 6-8am and 4-5pm all the cameras facing close to the sunrise and sunset get substantial high and changing scene scores. I am trying to compensate for this but still struggle though. I thought I could use this filter but after some experiments and seeing your examples, I suppose it won't help in my case.